# Representing integers as a sequence of bits

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitwise, bitset

Here is a class `Bits` that I wrote in order to deal with sequences of bits that also need to be interpreted as non-negative integers (in case you are familiar with VHDL, the class should be similar to the `unsigned` type from `numeric_std`).

Instances of `Bits` support:

- The built-in `int` and `len` functions giving the integer value and the number of bits, respectively.
- Formatting as strings using the built-in `hex`, `bin` and `oct` functions.
- Indexing and iteration over the individual bits (the least significant bit – on the *right* – is at index 0, so that `sum(b *  2**i for i, b in enumerate(x)) == int(x)` for any instance `x`).
- `append` and `extend` methods in analogy to the corresponding `list` and `deque` methods.
- `popleft` in analogy to `deque` and a method which I called `splitleft` and is the reverse operation of `extend` (but on the left side).
- The bitwise `__xor__` operation with another instance that doesn't have more bits.
- Conversion to and from `bytes`.

I deliberately did not implement any arithmetic operators, because I think the semantics are too ambiguous (e.g. should addition of instances with different numbers of bits be allowed, how many bits should the result have, what should happen in case of overflow, etc.). Also, in the special case of `+` and `*` confusion between the `int` and the `list` semantics could arise.

Other conceivable methods (`appendleft`, `extendleft`, `pop`(right), `split`(right)) or bitwise operators are not yet implemented because there wasn't any need yet.

Please have a look! Is the documentation clear? Are the error messages helpful? Are all corner cases handled properly?

```
from collections.abc import Sequence
from numbers import Integral

def _plural_bits(n):
    return '1 bit' if n == 1 else '{} bits'.format(n)

class Bits(Sequence):
    """Represent integer values as a sequence of bits."""

    def __init__(self, value=0, size=None):
        """Initialize instance with given integer value and number of bits.

        If size is left unspecified, the minimum number of bits necessary to
        represent the value is used.
        """
        if size is None:
            size = value.bit_length()
        for x in [value, size]:
            if not isinstance(x, Integral):
                raise TypeError('Expected integer argument: {}'.format(x))
        if size < 0:
            raise ValueError('Size must not be negative.')
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError('Cannot represent negative values.')
        elif value >= 2 ** size:
            raise ValueError('Cannot represent {} using {}.'
                             .format(value, _plural_bits(size)))
        self._value, self._size = value, size

    def copy(self):
        """Return a copy of self."""
        return Bits(value=self._value, size=self._size)

    @classmethod
    def all_ones(cls, n):
        """Return an instance with n bits where every bit is 1.

        >>> b = Bits.all_ones(5)
        >>> len(b)
        5
        >>> bin(b)
        '0b11111'
        """
        return cls(value=2 ** n - 1, size=n)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        """Return the i'th bit from the right (i = 0 -> LSB).

        >>> b = Bits(0b1101, 4)
        >>> [b[i] for i in reversed(range(4))]
        [1, 1, 0, 1]
        >>> all(int(x) == sum(b * 2**i for i, b in enumerate(Bits(x, 4)))
        ...     for x in range(16))
        True
        """
        if self._size == 0 or i >= self._size:
            raise IndexError('Bad index for {}-bit value: {}'
                             .format(self._size, i))
        i %= self._size  # support negative indexes
        return (self._value >> i) & 1

    @property
    def msb(self):
        """Return the most significant bit.

        >>> Bits(0b1000, 4).msb
        1
        >>> Bits(0b0111, 4).msb
        0
        """
        return self[-1]

    @property
    def lsb(self):
        """Return the least significant bit.

        >>> Bits(0b0001, 4).lsb
        1
        >>> Bits(0b1110, 4).lsb
        0
        """
        return self[0]

    def __len__(self):
        """Return the number of bits."""
        return self._size

    def __int__(self):
        """Return the integer value of the bits."""
        return self._value

    def __index__(self):
        """Support hex(), bin(), etc."""
        return self.__int__()

    def __xor__(self, other):
        """Return self ^ other.

        Integer arguments are implicitly converted to Bits.
        Argument must not have more bits than self.
        """
        if isinstance(other, Integral):
            other = Bits(other)
        if self._size < len(other):
            raise ValueError('Other operand has too many bits: {!r}'
                             .format(other))
        return Bits(self._value ^ int(other), self._size)

    def reversed(self):
        """Return an instance with the bits in reverse order.

        >>> b = Bits(0b1011, 4).reversed()
        >>> b
        Bits(value=13, size=4)
        >>> '{:04b}'.format(int(b))
        '1101'
        """
        value = sum(2 ** i * b for i, b in enumerate(reversed(self)))
        return Bits(value, self._size)

    def extend(self, other):
        """Extend self on the right side by other bits.

        >>> b = Bits(0x3, 2)
        >>> b.extend(Bits(0x10, 8))
        >>> hex(b)
        '0x310'
        >>> len(b)
        10
        """
        self._value = (self._value << len(other)) + int(other)
        self._size += len(other)

    def append(self, bit):
        """Append a single bit on the right side.

        >>> b = Bits(0x3, 2)
        >>> b.append(1)
        >>> int(b)
        7
        >>> len(b)
        3
        """
        self.extend(Bits(int(bit), size=1))

    def splitleft(self, n):
        """Remove and return the n leftmost bits.

        >>> b = Bits(0x310, 12)
        >>> b.splitleft(4)
        Bits(value=3, size=4)
        >>> b
        Bits(value=16, size=8)
        """
        remaining_size = self._size - n
        if remaining_size < 0:
            raise ValueError('Cannot split {} from {}-bit value.'
                             .format(_plural_bits(n), self._size))

        result_value = (self._value >> remaining_size) % (1 << n)
        self._value %= (1 << remaining_size)
        self._size = remaining_size
        return Bits(result_value, n)

    def popleft(self):
        """Remove and return the leftmost bit.

        >>> b = Bits(value=4, size=3)
        >>> b.popleft()
        Bits(value=1, size=1)
        >>> b
        Bits(value=0, size=2)
        """
        return self.splitleft(1)

    def to_bytes(self, byteorder):
        """Return an array of bytes representing the bits.

        >>> b = Bits(value=0x1abc, size=13)
        >>> b.to_bytes(byteorder='big').hex()
        '1abc'
        >>> b.to_bytes(byteorder='little').hex()
        'bc1a'
        """
        num_bytes = -(-self._size // 8)  # rounding up
        return self._value.to_bytes(num_bytes, byteorder)

    @classmethod
    def from_bytes(cls, bytes, size, byteorder):
        """Create an instance with the given size from an array of bytes.

        >>> Bits.from_bytes(bytes([0xbc, 0x1a]), size=13, byteorder='little')
        Bits(value=6844, size=13)
        """
        return cls(value=int.from_bytes(bytes, byteorder), size=size)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}(value={!r}, size={!r})'.format(
            self.__class__.__name__, self._value, self._size)
```

Comment: That's pretty nice IMHO

Comment: looks nice, you can do just some minor thing: group up methods (magic_methods, properties, classmethods, staticmethods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty good code and I do not have much to say besides nitpicks:

- `__init__` could be simplified a bit if you focused a bit more on `size` rather than `value`:

  ```
  def __init__(self, value=0, size=None):
      try:
          min_size = value.bit_length()
      except AttributeError:
          raise TypeError('Bits requires ints as \'value\'') from None
      if size is None:
          size = min_size

      if size < min_size:
          # Mimics int.to_bytes
          raise OverflowError('Cannot represent {} using {}.'.format(...))
      if value < 0:
          raise ValueError('Cannot represent negative values')

      self._value = value
      self._size = size
  ```
- Since instances of `Bits` **are** ints, you should have:

  ```
  def __int__(self):
      return self._value
  __index__ = __int__
  ```
- You may want to provide an `__iter__` method rather than relying on `__len__` + `__getitem__` to enable the iteration protocol. It allows to provide an "optimized" method, where you only `>> 1` for `self._size` times in a row instead of performing `>> n` for `n` in `range(self._size)`. Not sure if it is worth it, though, you may want to time it. Same remarks applies to `__reversed__`.
- I would have spelled `splitleft` and `popleft`: `split_left` and `pop_left`.
- You may want to consider using `self.__class__` instead of plain `Bits` when returning new instances.
- I’d add a `__str__` method allong the lines of:

  ```
  def __str__(self):
      return 'Bits({}:{})'.format(int(self), bin(self))
  ```

  Or something similar that allows to easily see both the int and digits sequence in one call.